# Hotlink protection excluding a particular URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

We have tried adding the below hotlink protection inorder to save the bandwidth.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?domain [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|PNG|png|jpeg|JPEG|mp4|MP4|mkv|MKV|webm|WEBM|ico|ICO)$ - [F]
```

This is working perfectly. Now, we want to exclude hotlink protection for the URL admin/thumbs (domain.tld/admin/thumbs/image.jpg) should be excluded from the hotlink protection.

We tried adding the below code however its not working. We searched on stackoverflow and multiple forums however none were helped us.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?domain [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/thumbs$
RewriteRule \.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|PNG|png|jpeg|JPEG|mp4|MP4|mkv|MKV|webm|WEBM|ico|ICO)$ - [F]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin/thumbs/?`

Comment: @ Pheonix Solutions did it work?

Comment: @Ivan86 No. It doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to set it up on my server as well and it currently isn't working properly. If i get it working I will let you know

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/thumbs$
> ```

This creates an exception for any URL that *ends with* `/admin/thumbs`, whereas it would seem you want to create an exception for any file in the `/admin/thumbs` subirectory, ie. any URL that *starts* `/admin/thumbs`.

The suggestion `!^admin/thumbs/?` in comments is incorrect, since the `REQUEST_URI` server variable always starts with a slash so the *condition* will always be successful and the request is potentially blocked.

You should use the *CondPattern* `!^/admin/thumbs($|/)` instead to exclude requests for `/admin/thumbs`, `/admin/thumbs/` and `/admin/thumbs/<anything>`, but not `/admin/thumbsomething`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/thumbs($|/)
```

Your existing rule can be further simplified/refined since the existing *conditions* that check the `HTTP_REFERER` are "the same", but also match too much. And the mixed case `RewriteRule` *pattern* can be *flattened* by using the `NC` (`nocase`) flag instead.

For example, the complete rule would become:

```
# Hotlink protection for images, except those in "/admin/thumbs/..."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example\.com($|/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/thumbs($|/)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|mp4|mkv|webm|ico)$ - [NC,F]
```

Note that this also blocks an *empty* `Referer` header. This includes direct requests (anyone typing the URL directly into the browser's address bar) and any user that has suppressed the `Referer` in their browser (which some users do for increased privacy).

---

#### Alternative solution with additional `.htaccess` file

Alternatively, you could create an additional `.htaccess` in the `/admin/thumbs/` subdirectory and simply disable the rewrite engine. For example:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

This overrides and prevents the hotlink-protection directives in the parent config from being processed when anything within this subdirectory is requested.